# How to add drawPolygon() to a button listener?

Tags: java, eclipse, button, event-handling

I'm trying to do an excercise about event listeners. To draw a triangle i used the drawPolygon method, but i don't know how to add it to the buttonListener to perform the actionListener.
That is a part of the code:

```
public class Triangle extends Figure {
            int x[];
            int y[];
            int n;

            Triangle(boolean f, Color c, int x, int y, int n) {
                super(f, c, x, y);
                int xPoints[];
                int yPoints[];
                int nPoints[];
            }

            @Override
            public void drawMySelf(Graphics g) {

                int xPoints[] = {80, 150, 80};
                int yPoints[] = {80, 150, 150};
                int nPoints = 3;

                Polygon P = new Polygon(x, y, n);
                if (filled)
                    g.fillPolygon(P);
                else g.drawPolygon(P);

            }
        }
@Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                String kommando = e.getActionCommand();

                int width = drawPanel.getWidth();
                int heigth = drawPanel.getHeight();


                if (kommando.equals("Cercle")) {

                    theFigures.add(new Circle(false, Color.BLUE, 20, 20, 50));

                 } else if (kommando.equals("Rektangle")) {
                    theFigures.add(new Rectangle(false, Color.BLACK, 300, 100,
                            150, 100));
                 } else if (kommando.equals("Triangele")) {
                    theFigures.add(___my problem is here___); 
                 }  else if (kommando.equals("Cercle rempli")) {
                     theFigures.add(new Circle(true, Color.YELLOW, 50, 100, 100));
                 }  else if (kommando.equals("Rektangle rempli")) {
                     theFigures.add(new Rectangle(true, Color.GREEN, 500, 50,
                                100, 250));


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create some buttons (for circle, rectangle etc.),  and configure them via the setActionCommand-method. Then add your actionListener with button.addActionListener to it. I Think [this](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/swing/jbutton/set-action-command-for-jbutton/) article will help you.

Comment: This is a good example, but my request is how to add the drawPolygone() her: theFigures.add(new Triangle(.......)); look at my code. I already created buttons and everything. I want to display a triangle when i press the button. Otherwise thx for ur answer.

Comment: what about:  theFigures.add(new Triangle(false, Color.YELLOW, 50, 100, 100));